# How do I add an image to a collection to shopify with the ruby api gem

Tags: ruby, shopify

I have attempted 
coll = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(id)
coll.image = {"src"=>"..."}
and a bazillion other methods - 
nothing seems to work

Comment: This doesn't help us help you. We need a sample of your code demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Shopify API docs](http://docs.shopify.com/api/smartcollection#update) provide an example of how to update the SmartCollection image:

```
collection = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(id)
collection.image = { attachment: "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==\n" }
collection.save
```

The `attachment` should be base64 encoded.

It should also be possible to specify a `src` where Shopify should download the image.

```
collection = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(id)
collection.image = { src: "http://example.com/rails_logo.gif" }
collection.save
```